# JS Accordion open first tab by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I want to open first tab by default on my accordion. I have been trying different solutions, but nothing worked for me.

**Here is my JS and HTML:**

```js
 $('.accordion').each(function () {
        var $accordian = $(this);
        $accordian.find('.accordion-head').on('click', function () {
            $(this).parent().find(".accordion-head").removeClass('open close');
            $(this).removeClass('open').addClass('close');
            $accordian.find('.accordion-body').slideUp();
            if (!$(this).next().is(':visible')) {
                $(this).removeClass('close').addClass('open');
                $(this).next().slideDown();
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-head">
    Title here <div class="arrow down"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-body">
    copy goes here
    </div>
    
    <div class="accordion-head">
    Title here <div class="arrow down"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-body">
    copy goes here
    </div>
    
    <div class="accordion-head">
    Title here <div class="arrow down"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-body">
    copy goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help.